# Induction of graphs ????

Tags: graph-theory, induction

For a graph theoretical purposes, the n-dimensional cube Q_n is a simple graph whose vertices are the 2^n points (x_1... x_n) in R^n. So that for i in [n] either x_i=1 or 0, and in which two vertices are adjacent if they agree in exactly n-1 coordinates. show that if n>2 then Q_n has a hamiltonian cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The base case is trivial.  Assume there exists a Hamiltonian cycle for $n$ dimensions.  Then consider the graph of the $(n+1)$-dimensional cube.  This can be partitioned into two identical copies of the $n$-dimensional cube, with one adjacent hyperface.  Follow the Hamiltonian cycle on the $n$-dimensional cube except for one edge where the vertices it is incident on are adjacent to the second cube.  At the end of this path, jump to the mirror cube and follow a mirror path.  Then return to the original cube to complete the Hamiltonian cycle.

I hope that made sense!